# SpringBoot Run command is giving an error about duplicate Slf4j library loading

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, microservices

I am new to spring-boot. I did "mvn clean install" build got success. Then I am navigate to specific module(sub folder) then I am trying to execute `mvn spring-boot: run` then I am getting below error.

> LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the
>   classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation
>   (class org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory loaded from
>   file:/root/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.12/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar).
>   If you are using Weblogic you will need to add 'org.slf4j' to
>   prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml Object of class
>   [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory] must be an instance of class
>   ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What logger are you using?

Comment: @vlad324 I am using slf4j

Comment: Find out your dependencies using `mvn dependency:tree`. That will indicate whats loading the duplicate slf4j lib.

Comment: @ParthipanSubramaniam do you have some configuration for logger in your app?

Comment: Thank you so much guys I have analyzed maven dependcy tree and I came to know org.apache.phoenix is internally calling slf4j. I have excluded it :)